# ¿como puedo solucionar que al extraer un texto de mysql salga estructurado?

Tags: php

tengo guardado un texto tipo varchar en una tabla mysql, el texto aparece con formato es decir con sus espacios en la tabla pero cuado lo muestro en mi documento php me muestra una sopa completa, no respeta los punto y aparte ni las separaciones.
que puedo hacer ?
asi es como lo hago normalmente

```
<?php echo $r['texto']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver utilizando el método [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.nl2br.php) que transforma los saltos de línea de texto (nl = new line) a saltos de línea de HTML (con `<br>`).

Sería así:

```
<?php echo nl2br($descripcion); ?>
```